# Flex Mobile: Unable to play AAC audio in Android devices

Tags: android, apache-flex, audio, air, aac

I am building a Flex mobile app that needs to play audio with the AAC format. In AIR simulator everything works fine, but when I test it in an Android device, this format just doesn't play.

Besides, any videos (FLV/MP4) that uses AAC as its audio format have no sound when tested in Android.

I searched for a long time but couldn't find a solution for this. I know that FlashPlayer has supported this format a long time ago.

So is this a bug? Or how can I play AAC audio in android devices?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally got around to solve this. I thought I was using AIR 3.4, but actually I was using AIR 3.1. Upgrading it to above 3.4 solves this.

The following is some information that might be useful:
In Flash Builder 4.7, the AIR SDK is in "Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/sdks/4.6.0/". Inside this folder, the version of "bin/adl.exe" is 3.1. And this is the default sdk used.
However, inside the "Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722/AIRSDK", the version of "bin/adl.exe" is 3.4.